# CrudRepository save method doesnt save any in db

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data

I have very strange behavior. I have created repository which extends CrudRepository. All default methods works fine except save method. It doesnt save new entity to db. I need to save new entity with id which I provide. If I provide existing id in db - then save updates this entity successfully, but if I set new id - then nothing, not even error.
My repo:

```
import com.xxx.yyy.entities.Game;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface GameRepository extends CrudRepository<Game, Integer> {}
```

My entity:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;

import java.util.Objects;

@Table("game_info")
public class Game {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int wager;

    setters and getters
```

My service:

```
public void addGame() {

    Game g = new Game();
    g.setId(10);
    g.setName("Name");
    g.saveWager(22);

    gameRepository.save(game);
}
```

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `game_info`
(
    `id`        INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unique identifier of the Game',
    `name`      VARCHAR(32)  NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of the Game',
    `wager`     INT          NOT NULL COMMENT 'Wager of the Game',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE (`name`)
);
```

Comment: Provide logs all possible logs, from startup, during the actual persistence of a data. Do you have an empty non private contructor?

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: I`m using MySQL

Answer (score 1):

It seams that its no way to save entity with seted id. I have to write new insert method like this:

```
@Modifying
@Query("INSERT INTO `game_info` (`id`, `name`, `wager`) VALUES (:id, :name, :wager)")
void addGame(@Param("id") int id, @Param("name") String name, @Param("wager") Integer wager);
```